# Peculiar variations in command results

Tags: bash

There are some commands which result in different results in bash when typed into a window vs. when stored in a file and run with the "." operator.

Example, 3 lines in "commands3.txt"

```
date  > 1.killme ; sleep  5  ; date  >> 1.killme
date  > 2.killme ; sleep  5  ; date  >> 2.killme
date  > 3.killme ; sleep  5  ; date  >> 3.killme
```

Type the first line into a bash shell and the resulting "1.killme" file has two lines with two time stamps.  However do:

```
. commands3.txt
```

And each line has just one time stamp (the second, which overwrites the first.)

Change the file to this:

```
date  > 1.killme ; echo 1; sleep  5  ; date  >>1.killme; echo 2
date  > 2.killme ; echo 1; sleep  5  ; date  >>2.killme; echo 2
date  > 3.killme ; echo 1; sleep  5  ; date  >>3.killme; echo 2
```

and do the dot file method again and this time each file will have both time stamps.  Change it to this:

```
date  > 1.killme ; sleep  5  ; date  >>1.killme;
date  > 2.killme ; sleep  5  ; date  >>2.killme;
date  > 3.killme ; sleep  5  ; date  >>3.killme;
```

and do

```
. commands3.txt
```

And the files will again contain both time stamps, but at the expense of emitting ": command not found..." on every line.

If this is as it should be, can somebody please explain why bash is doing this?

bash 4.2.46, date 8.22, on Centos 7

Thanks

EDIT:  as the answers said it would be, there were embedded \r in the commands3.txt file.  Apparently cut/paste into the xterm silently removes those somehow.

Thanks all.

Comment: I suspect your file has Windows CRLF newlines, fix it with `dos2unix`.

Comment: Look for files named `1.killme\r`, `2.killme\r`, and `3.killme\r`.